# Did the League of Villains kill Kai Chisaki?

Tags: my-hero-academia

Spoilers (for those who haven't read the manga or reached chapter 160) :

> After being defeated by Eri and Midoriya, Chisaki was under police custody. As the police were transporting him to jail, the League of Villains attacked the police cars. The last time we saw Chisaki was when he was still tied up surrounded by the wreckage. During the last time we see him, the League of Villains were taunting him about his failures and even cut his arms off. They also take his quirk drug which he (Chisaki) basically devoted most of his life to making.
>
>  After that, we see an explosion, but we don't know if they exploded Chisaki or trapped him in a tiny orb by using Atsuhiro Sako's power to keep him because I noticed earlier Atsuhiro was holding an orb above Chisaki (but after that Chisaki wasn't inside the orb, the League was still talking to him). His current state is unknown and I was wondering if anyone knew the author ever said something about his current state or if I missed something while reading the manga.

Answer (score 3):

While his current state is "unknown", we can assume that *the League of Villians did not kill Kai Chisaki*.

> In **Chapter 160** of the VIZ translations, Overhaul himself, asked Tomura if he (Tomura) was going to kill him (Overhaul), to which Tomura replied no, and that he thought up of something 'worse'. [image: ![enter image description here]

Regarding that orb you mentioned, Atsuhiro was holding it over Overhaul but he did not compress him, *he just compressed part of Overhaul's arm*, severing it as seen below.

> [image]

Later on, we see Tomura saying to Overhaul to 'sit back and have a nice life' after severing his other arm, and robbing him of his quirk, which Chisaki relied heavily on. *Overhauls expression showed fear at the thought of spending his life with no Quirk*, which as the [wiki](http://bokunoheroacademia.wikia.com/wiki/Kai_Chisaki#Personality) noted, is ironic, since he spent his life eradicating Quirks from people.

> [image]

Finally, the first panel of the last page of chapter 160, shows something already burning in the background but on the second panel, *we still see Overhaul alive with no hint of him being burned*, with the same expression of fear as seen in the previous page. This confirms the fact that *Tomura wanted Overhaul to suffer first, in revenge* for everything he had done against the League of Villains.

> [image]

Answer (score 1):

Episode 77 of the anime makes it perfectly clear that Overhaul is **still alive**.

First of all, the fire seen in the final panel of Chapter 160 is shown to be a considerable distance away from Overhaul, and couldn't possibly have reached him:

> [image]

Secondly, as Shigaraki and the League of Villains begin to walk away, Overhaul begins screaming in anguish:

> [image]

...and he's still screaming as the scene ends.

Answer (score 0):

As you stated current status of him is unknown. We can assume he is not dead since League of Villains could nuke the convoy and killing everybody. However that wouldn't benefit them like at all. They attacked the convoy because they want them alive. We can assume that they are probably after quirk drug.

Answer (score 0):

In the 18th volume of My Hero Academia, I think it was All Might that mentioned the attack on the ambulance to Midoriya. Midoriya said, Wait... So you mean Chisaki was.... by the League of Villains?